# Watson's strategic chess pgn file

Tags: pgn

I am looking for the PGN file corresponding to Watson's strategic chess opening repertoire for white; is it available? If the PGN is not available, I would be interested to know what other opening books have a PGN companion available.

as a side note I've though about writing a python script to read in chess books as PDF and extracting the variations as PGN. Has anyone done this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that PGN files are just plain text, then you can create your own.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation) you need 7 tags:

> PGN data for archival storage is required to provide seven bracketed fields, referred to as "tags"...:
>
> 1. Event
> 2. Site
> 3. Date: the starting date of the game, in YYYY.MM.DD form. ?? is used for unknown values
> 4. Round
> 5. White: the player of the white pieces, in Lastname, Firstname format.
> 6. Black: the player of the black pieces, same format as White.
> 7. Result: the result of the game. This can only have four possible values: 1-0 (White won), 0-1 (Black won), 1/2-1/2 (Draw), or * (other, e.g., the game is ongoing).

An example might be:

[Event "QGA: Main line with 7.Bd3"] 
[Site "?"] 
[Date "????.??.??"] 
[Round "?"] 
[White "Me"] 
[Black "The other guy"] 
[Result "*"]

1. d4 d5 2. c4 dxc4 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. e3 e6 5. Bxc4 c5 6. O-O a6 7. Bd3 *